# iOS Beacon Monitoring - didEnterRegion is Called only after the didExitRegion is triggered for a monitored region

Tags: ios, ibeacon

My application is monitoring for beacon regions. When application launches, the didEnterRegion is called & it detects a region.. Again the didEnterRegions is called only the didExitRegion is called for the monitored beacon region...

Is this the way the Beacon Monitoring works?

Comment: I think you are asking if you will only receive another call to `didEnterRegion` if you exit the region (and receive a call to `didExitRegion`)?  The answer is Yes - You can't enter a region again unless you have exited it

Comment: @Paulw11 is correct.  I'd suggest making this comment an answer so it can be accepted.  That way other folks who find this question will see that this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the calls to `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` are effectively triggered when you cross the region boundary.  When you cross the boundary (or an iBeacon signal is first received) your `didEnterRegion` method will be called for that beacon region.  You won't receive any further calls to `didEnterRegion` for that beacon region until you have left the region (and received a corresponding call to `didExitRegion`).

When you are in a region you can 'range' the beacon to receive repeated updates with the beacon's signal strength (and therefore approximate range)